# What are examples of comments that tell you WHY instead of HOW or WHAT?

Tags: comments, code-documentation

First of all, in this question I'd like to stay away from the polemic on whether source code commenting is good or bad. I'm just trying to understand more clearly what people mean when they talk about comments that tell you WHY, WHAT or HOW.

We often see guidelines like "Comments should tell you WHY; code itself should tell you HOW". It is easy to agree with the statement on an abstract level. However, people usually drop this like a dogma, and leave the room without further explanation. I've seen this used in so many different places and contexts, that it looks like people can agree on the catchphrase, but they seem to be talking about different things entirely.

So, back to the question: if comments should tell you WHY, what is this WHY we are talking about? Is this the reason why that piece of code exists in the first place? Is this what that piece code should be doing? I would really appreciate if someone could give a clear explanation, and then add some good examples (bad examples are not really needed, but fell free to add them for contrast).

Please do not immediately close this question as duplicate or polemic. I have tried hard to make it very objective. There are many questions on whether comments are good or bad, but no one that addresses the specific question of what are good examples of comments that tell you WHY.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable question for SO. More likely programmers.SE. Maybe this already helps: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119600/beginners-guide-to-writing-comments.

Comment: Thanks Felix, this surely helps. On the other hand, that thread has many examples of people dropping that same commandment, and then not providing a clear explanation or good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Comments serve two main purposes:

- to summarise. Many would say "why document this method when we can just read the code?", but one line of text that describes what a method is for/what it does, can often be much faster to read and easier to understand than 30 lines of code, especially if that code calls other methods that you may need to read as well...
- to explain the things that are not obvious from the code - the WHY, or more detail on the how. Simple examples include "we must add the new XmlElement and then remove the old one, as the ReplaceChild method in .net does not work!", or "Uses an iterative Newton-Raphson approach to solve for X ", or "we must not close the port here because the reading thread may still be running", or "use this method where performance is critical, but beware that this method may provide a result that is in error by up to 5%"